# Show partial sums are bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show$$\sum_{n=3}^N(-1)^{\left\lfloor(n^3+n+1)/(3n^2-1)\right\rfloor}$$ is bounded. It seems like the summed sequence is just $-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,...$, so the partial sums are clearly bounded, but I don't know how to prove that's actually the case.

Comment: I'm aware there was a similar question, namely https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094422/convergence-of-sum-n-2-infty-1-left-lfloor-n3n1-over-3n2-1-ri but my problem wasn't answered there

Comment: The question about the sums being bounded cannot be answered by looking at individual terms. In this case it is all about the frequencies of $\pm1$s within the sequence. For example, if for each $k$ the +1s outnumber the -1s with $n$ upto $N=2^k$ by the tiny amount of $\log_2k$, then the sums will be unbounded. You might need to use $N=2^{2^{100}}$ to get sums $\ge100$, but that's exactly the point. So I'm afraid you are nowhere near a solution when you extrapolate from the first six terms.

Comment: Like what happened [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2582283/11619)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I'm aware of that, but from explicitly calculating some of the first terms I've notices they change the sign every 3 terms, so if that's the case boundedness is trivial. So my problem is, how do I show that this sequence always changes the sign every 3 terms and doesn't change this behavior for sufficiently large indices

Comment: Ok. Rigel's answer shows how to do that. I was mislead by you not telling explicitly that you observed the sequence to repeat in a period of six. Which is really the key! No harm done. Sorry about the extra fuss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1} = \frac{n}{3} + \frac{4n+3}{3(3n^2-1)} =: \frac{n}{3} + a_n\,,
$$
and that $(a_n)$ is positive and monotone decreasing, and $a_n < 1/3$ for every $n>2$.
Hence, for $n\geq 3$, you have that 
$$
\lfloor \frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1} \rfloor
= \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor,
$$
so that your sum is bounded for every $N$.